# Javascript not being called in @Html.ActionLink

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following javascript test.js file:

```
$("#addItem").click(function () {
    alert("yup");
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) { $("#bandRows").append(html); }
    });
    return false;
});
```

That I want to use to inject some HTML into the "bandRows" div on a page.  I'm using Razor in an MVC 3 app like so:

**The Index View**, which contains the link that, when clicked injects a partial view HTML:

```
@model IEnumerable<TariffBand>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="=@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js")"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="=@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="=@Url.Content("~/Scripts/test.js")"></script>

    <h2>Index</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    <div id="bandRows">
        @foreach (var band in Model)
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("BandEditorRow", band);
        }
    </div>

    @Html.ActionLink("Add band...", "Add", null, new { id = "addItem" })

    <input type="submit" value = "Done" />
```

At the moment, when I click on the link the javascript is not being called - the alert box is not being displayed - and the link just navigates to the "Add" partial view rather than injecting it into the 'bandRows' div.

Can anyone tell me why?  I haven't used javascript before so I've obviously done something daft but can't work it out for the life of me.

**EDIT** - I have amended the .js file so the handler is for click not onclick.  I have also tried amending the html helper to:

`@Html.ActionLink("add band...", "Add", null, new { onclick = "addItem" }` but still no dice.

Thanks
David

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
$("#addItem").onclick(function ()
```

There is nothing like `$.onclick`.

This will be

```
$("#addItem").click(function ()
```

## Edit

`$().ajax({` should be `$.ajax({`

and the whole code should be within `document.ready()` like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#addItem").click(function (){
   .
   .
   .
});
```

## Edit - 2

As you have admitted that you are very new to javascript world, I am giving the detail code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="=@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")"></script>
@* <script type="text/javascript" src="=@Url.Content("~/Scripts/test.js")"></script> *@

<h2>Index</h2>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#addItem").click(function (){
            alert("yup");
            $.ajax({
                url: this.href,
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) { 
                    $("#bandRows").append(html); 
                }
            });
            return false;
        };  
    });
</script>
```

`document ready` is a very preliminary thing you need to learn when starting `jQuery`. [This](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) is the API documentation of `ready` event. And [here](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready) is a tutorial for understanding `document ready`.

Comment: Thanks Mohayemin, but when I change to .click the script is still not called.

Comment: Not even the alert? Have you added the script in `document.ready()`?

Comment: Not even the alert!  The script is added as per the .cshtml file above, so not sure if that means yes or no - apols I have never used javascript before (as you can probably tell).  How would I add a script in document.ready()?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check and let me know. I will not be avalable for next 2 hours. I hope I have added everything you need.

Comment: Oh I see, I have missed something. Your javascript is in a separate file. Well, I would do this javascript in the view instead (in a `<script>` tag) because the code does not seem to be reusable. Its strictly valid for this particular page only, right?

Comment: Yup - I only want the script to be called from this page.